# PhoneGap + ajaxComplete works in all browsers but not on iOS when loaded from PhoneGap.

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application which relies quite heavily on the jQuery ajaxComplete function.

This appears to be working in all browsers (including Safari on iOS), but is not working on iOS when loaded from PhoneGap.

It is as though the ajaxComplete handler is completely removed by PhoneGap when the page loads.

Does any one have any experience with this?

Thanks in advanced,

Aaron

Comment: Could you show us some parts of the code ?

Comment: Hi, it turns out that this is caused by browsers worrying about security (which is good, I suppose). It was working in the browser because we were running it over HTTP, but it failed on the devices because it was opening the HTML file just as an ordinary file.

It's weird that we were still enable to get the XHR response, but just wasn't being passed into the ajaxComplete.

Thanks anyway

Comment: To clarify, is this because PhoneGap opens the HTML via the File URI Scheme?

Comment: Unfortunately that does appear to be the case.

Answer (score 5):

To allow AJAX in iOS applications, we must modify ExternalHosts

- In XCode, open Resources/phonegap.plist
- Click ExternalHosts, add your external host to the list

Ex: *.your-ajax-site.com

Note: just add hostname, NOT including protocol,  NOT http://

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like this:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend:function(){...},
  complete:function(){...},
  success:function(){...}
 });
```